# Having problems getting the ith character in a string

Tags: c++, string, char

I want to access the `ith` `char` in `str`

```c++
int main() {
    string str = "5.9x^11+x^3–3x^10";
    for(int i = 0; i<17; i++){
        cout<<i<<": ";
        cout<<str.at(i)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what I expect:

```
0: 5
1: .
2: 9
3: x
4: ^
5: 1
6: 1
7: +
8: x
9: ^
10: 3
11: -
12: 3
13: x
14: ^
15: 1
16: 0
```

what I get:

```
0: 5
1: .
2: 9
3: x
4: ^
5: 1
6: 1
7: +
8: x
9: ^
10: 3
11: \342
12: \200
13: \223
14: 3
15: x
16: ^
```

I don't understand why the values at `11-13` aren't `-,3,x` respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character at position 11 is not the Unicode character `U+002D MINUS`, like you are expecting.  It's actually the Unicode character `U+2013 EN DASH`.  In UTF-8, `U+2013` is encoded as the byte sequence `0xE2 0x80 0x93` (`\342 \200 \223` in octal).

This typically happens when one uses a dumb word processor to write code, and auto-correct is enabled. That would be my guess as to what happened here.

Answer (score 4):

The "–" in your string is not - (ASCII 0x2D) but [U+2013](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).

The sequence `\342 \200 \223` seems in octet and converting it to hex, it can be written as `0xE2 0x80 0x93` and that is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) representation of the character.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string str = "5.9x^11+x^3-3x^10";
for(int i = 0; i<17; i++){
    cout<<i<<": ";
    cout<<str.at(i)<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

All that needed to be changed was the minus sign, after it was deleted and retyped it worked as intended.